# How to deal with the absolute value sign in the process of solving differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Imagine we are given a differential equation as follows
$$y'\sin x-y\cos x=0,$$
which seems to be very simple. We can solve it like this:
\begin{align*}
&y'\sin x-y\cos x=0\\
\implies &\frac{{\rm d}y}{y}=\cot x{\rm d}x\\
\implies &\int \frac{{\rm d}y}{y}=\int \cot x{\rm d}x\\
\implies &\ln y=\ln\sin x+C'\\
\implies &y=e^{\ln\sin x+C'}\\
\implies &y=C\sin x.
\end{align*}

Right? May be. But wait! Notice the transformation or operation from the the 3rd line to the 4th line. In general, we ought to write as these:
$$\int \frac{{\rm d}y}{y}=\ln |y|+C_1,~~~\int \cot x{\rm d}x=\ln|\sin x|+C_2,$$
when we are finding the indefinite integral, namely, we should add an absolute value sign in the result.

Of course, sometimes, you can cancel the sign in the final result again, indeed. But some books boldly omit the sign in the process. This is irresponsible negligence, or a valid trick?

Comment: Absolute value signs are necessary. However, in certain intervals you can argue that not all choices of $\pm$ signs are necessary. For example, if you want solutions in $(0,\pi)$ there are two solutions $y=C\sin\, x$ and $y=-C\sin\, x$; $y$ cannot change sign within the interval.

Comment: See it as $C=sign(y_0)\,sign(\sin(x_0))e^{C'}$, $y=0$ is a solution that can not be crossed by another solution, and the domain has to exclude the roots of the $\sin x$, all signs are constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deal with it like this

\begin{align} 
\ln|y| &= \ln|\sin x| + C_2-C_1 \\
|y| &= e^{C_2-C_1}|\sin x| \\
y &= \pm e^{C_2-C_1}\sin x
\end{align}

Where one of the $\pm$ signs is applied. You then rewrite $C = \pm e^{C_2-C_1}$ to get the desired result. Clearly $C$ can be either positive or negative, depending on the given initial value.

Comment: $C$ could be $0$?

Comment: Before anything happends, you should've pointed out that $y=0$ is a trivial solution. Then you go on to solve the equation for $y\ne 0$ (since you need to divide by $y$ in one step). In the end, the trivial solution happens to fit, so $C=0$ is included.